# SQL query takes less time in MYSQL, take more in PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance, query-performance

I have `MYISAM` table and i wrote a `FULL-TEXT` SQL query.
When i execute this query, it takes < 0.53 seconds 
But when i execute this php+mysql application, it takes more than 1-2 minutes

#### Query:

```
select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as `cand_full_name`, email 
from resumes WHERE MATCH (thesis_text) AGAINST ('-java -j2ee -oracle -mysql -software' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

#### Update 1:

I am using `mysqli_query($this->dbconnection, $this->query)` in query

#### Update 2:

PHP Code http://codepad.org/qufZBC16

#### Note :

I am not running any other sql query on this page.

Any Idea, why it's taking more time.

Comment: This query works? No syntax issues?

Comment: How are you running it in PHP?

Comment: @CurtisMattoon I am using `mysqli_query($this->dbconnection, $this->query)` in query

Comment: How large is your result? A lot of time is spent in PHP parsing the response if there are a lot of rows. There's also the issue of network overhead if you're connecting to a remote DB server vs running mysql CLI on the server itself.

Comment: @CurtisMattoon I get more than 500 records but i use `LIMIT` and `local` Server

Comment: this query has syntax issues. did you just not copy it over correctly?

Comment: Can you update your question to include your ACTUAL query that you're running? `LIMIT` isn't mentioned anywhere in your question. Also, have you tried `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @CurtisMattoon I have updated the question with orginal code 
http://codepad.org/qufZBC16

Answer (score 0):

Its very likely to be a charset issue. Set the charset after connection to speed up query

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php#refsect1-mysqli.set-charset-description

I'm not sure what charset your data Is stored in

Comment: Your crystal ball must be working really well today ;)

Comment: if this is the case maybe you could provide for the OP a way to do that? (make it a better answer for other passers by) :)